# CSS: Curved corner + extension

Tags: html, css

How can I get the element in the attached pic?

[image]

I need a line + curve to right at top + extension.

I can use div's, span or another idea if you have.

I tried to use 2 divs with round borders. But they don't connect in a pretty way in the corner.

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything ? Where are you failing ?

Comment: I tried to use 2 divs with round borders. But they don't connect in a pretty way in the corner.

Comment: it seems a simple border-radius, no ?

Comment: Perhaps post the code you've tried already and *exactly* how you expect it to look.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the dot in the corner. It's not particularly robust to change, and it will currently only work on a white background. However, with some SCSS and variables, it would be a lot cleaner.

The biggest issue I have with it is that the surrounding box is required to have a `relative` position, which might affect layout elsewhere.

```css
.fancy {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.fancy::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: -11px;
  content: "";
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 11px;
  background-color: gray;
}

p {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<p class="fancy">
  Some text
</p>
```

The **padding around the dot** is given by the `border-width` (`4px`).

The **colour of the dot** is defined by the `background-color`.

The places where `11px` is used are computed by the `border-width` + the [`height` (or `width`) / 2] and used to keep the dot circular and in the corner.

It's a little ambiguous what you want. If you wanted the title block in there too, then add this:

```css
.fancy {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.fancy .title {
  display: table;
  margin-top: -2.2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border: 6px solid white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #99ccff;
}

p {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<p class="fancy">
  <span class="title">A fancy title</span>
  Some text with a fancy title.
</p>
```

Comment: @Druckies, thanks for the help but I actually ment the round corner on the top, with the marked arrow. Can you give a hand with it?

Comment: That's just a `border-radius`, which you seem to have already used in your question, so I don't understand exactly what you want.

Comment: In what way? The only difference is the colour and that you put your arrow on the top-left corner but then posted a picture of the bottom-left corner.

Comment: Maybe the color confuses me.